# Crafter CMS - How to set default values for Checkbox Group field?

Tags: content-management-system, crafter-cms

I need to set default values for a "Grouped Checkboxes" field.
The Checkbox is using a configured list datasource.

I did set the "Default Value" option as one of the configured list options's key, however I see no default checked option being displayed when trying to create new content.

Answer (score 1):

You can set it by JQuery

```
$('.GroupedCheckedboxes').prop('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is a gap there at the moment.  I've created an enhancement request to add support for this here:
https://github.com/craftercms/craftercms/issues/2566

In the ticket, I've also provided a small workaround patch you can make to the group checkbox control which will allow you to set default values.

I am not sure if the solution to my enhancement request will be the same as my workaround so you will want to keep an eye on that ticket.